# How to add a cell to a list

Tags: list, calculator

On a Casio graphical calculator, specifically the fx-CG50, you have the ability to create and manipulate lists using their own built-in language, Casio Basic.

I’m writing a program using this, and need to add a cell to a pre-existing list, to increase its length. I can’t find anything in the user guide suggesting how one might achieve this, so I don’t really know how to.

I’m sure I could manage this with some long winded approach, but efficiency is of utmost importance due to the limited process power of the calculator. So is there some easy way to achieve this?

There isn’t a tag for Casio Basic, so I’m unable to add this to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve now found that the best way to do this is to use the built-in `Augment` function. Just simply joining the existing list with a new list with a dimension of 1.

```
Augment(List 1, {0})->List1
```

This just adds the value onto the end on the list, and overwrites itself.